# Generate incremented random numbers between 0 to 100 every second where new number should be greater than the previous nymber

Tags: javascript, random, counter, increment

I need a javascript where with every second call i get a random number between 0-100 where current number should be greater than previous number. I wrote a code to get random numbers every second but stuck at generating it with increment.

```
<script>
var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[3];
 var i = 100;
(function randNumber() {
        var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * i) + 1);
        span.innerHTML = "RandNumber: " + a;
        setTimeout( randNumber, 1000);
})();
```

Note : The numbers should generate randomly.
example result may be : `2,5,7,8,22,23,34,56,78,88.....`

Comment: What if the first random number is 100? :)

Comment: :) thats a nice question but its just a part of my module so, even if i get 100 at first go my work gets done. But yeah, its my bad i didn't mention about the exit part. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson : What if i want the loop to return atleast 30 random numbers before exiting? how can that be done?

Comment: @RahulUkil Instead of increasing to a number between the current one and your max, just increase by a random number between 1 an d `(max-min) / steps`.

Comment: @Sirko can you please give me the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not create a new random number between zero and your maximum (`i`), but just between the last created number (`lastNumber`) and max (`i`).
Also you might want to stop, when the random numbers reached the maximum.

```
var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[3],
    i = 100,
    lastNumber = 0;
function randNumber() {

   lastNumber = lastNumber + Math.floor( Math.random() * (i - lastNumber) + 1 );

   span.innerHTML = lastNumber;

   if( lastNumber < i ) {
     setTimeout( randNumber, 1000 );
   }
}

randNumber();
```

---

AS for the comments and the requirement of a minimum amount of steps until reaching the maximum:

In each iteration, just increase you number by a random value between `1` and (`(max - min) / steps`. It is pretty much the same code as above.

```
var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[3],
    max = 100,
    min = 0,
    lastNumber = 0,
    minSteps = 30;

// how wide can the average step be at most?
var stepWidth = (max - min) / minSteps;

function randNumber() {

   lastNumber = lastNumber + Math.floor( Math.random() * stepWidth + 1 );

   span.innerHTML = lastNumber;

   if( lastNumber < max ) {
     setTimeout( randNumber, 1000 );
   }
}

randNumber();
```

Comment: Just a query is it possible to always return minimum 30 random numbers before exiting, and Yeah, you are right i was just stuck at the random generation of number so i asked about that and of course it will have and exit part thanks for adding that in your code. Hope your piece of code will work in my module. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :D you deserve a beer :D you saved my time. Just wanted to mention in the if condition "i" should be replaced by "max" the name of the variable :D thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you extract the "between two numbers" logic into its own function like this, this becomes a lot easier. This way, you just generate a number between your last generated number and your maximum.

```
var max = 100
var last_number = 1



var interval_id = setInterval(function(){
    last_number = get_random_number_greater_between(last_number, max)

    span.innerHTML = "RandNumber: " + last_number;

    if(last_number >= max){
        window.clearInterval(interval_id)
    } 
}, 1000)

function get_random_number_greater_between(low, high){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1) + low);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
// generate a random number from 0 to max - 1.

function rand(max) {
    return Math.floor(max * Math.random());
}

// generate a random number from min to max.

function range(min, max) {
    return min + rand(1 + max - min);
}

// the loop function

function next(n, callback) {
    var m = range(n, 100);
    if (m < 100) setTimeout(next, 1000, m + 1, callback);
    callback(m);
}

var span = document.getElementById("rand");

next(0, function (m) {
    span.innerHTML = "Random number: " + m;
});
```

```html
<span id="rand"></span>
```